# Solve for t in overdamped 2nd order DE with non-integer constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

How would I rearrange an equation like this where there are 4 unique constants that are non-integers in front of the exponent and in front of e so as to solve for t?

$$x(t) = Ae^{Bt} + Ce^{Dt}$$

If A and C were equal this would be possible, but all four are unique and non-integers. Is it even possible?

I am trying to determine at what time $t$,  $x(t)$ will equal some value. Naturally there is a range for which this equation will have a solution but I can't seem to get anywhere with my algebra.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually there are boundary conditions that helps to determine the constants of integration. Otherwise your solution may not be unique.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, just looking at this equation regardless of where it came from in terms of how the DE was solved, can it be rearranged to solve for t?

Comment: No it cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions (powers, trig, exp. ln).

Comment: @Paul any way you are aware of to either approximate a solution or use a non-elementary function?

Comment: Newton's method will give you an approximate numerical solution pretty quickly, for known values of the constants..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paul commented, taking into account all the conditions described, only numeric methods will give the solution.

Where I see a potential problem is that you could have zero, one or two solutions.

Consider
$$x(t) = Ae^{Bt} + Ce^{Dt}$$ 
$$x'(t)= ABe^{Bt} + CDe^{Dt}$$
$$x''(t)= AB^2e^{Bt} + CD^2e^{Dt}$$

The first derivative would potentially cancel for
$$t_*=-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{A B}{C D}\right)}{B-D}$$ which does not exist in the real domain if $ABCD >0$. This is the "nice" case and Newton method will work like a charm if you consider for the zero of the better conditioned function
$$f(t)=\log(Ae^{Bt} + Ce^{Dt})-\log(x)\tag 1$$ which will almost look like a straight line.

For example, consider the case $A=234$, $B=0.345$, $C=567$, $D=0.123$, $x=123456$. Plot the original function and its transform to see how different is the problem.

Being lazy, let us start iterating with $t_0=0$; Newton method will generate the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 26.81753360 \\
 2 & 18.11584802 \\
 3 & 18.04389549 \\
 4 & 18.04388025
\end{array}
\right)$$

But, if $ABCD <0$ this would be a different story.